# Want to check who are all Manager in the table and how many count are under manager

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 columns in a table:

```
emp_id  emp_name    job_name    manager_id
------------------------------------------
1        A          PRESIDENT     0
2        B          MANAGER       1
3        C          MANAGER       1
4        D          A M           1
5        E          A M           2
6        F          AM            2
7        G          AM            3
```

Query:

```
SELECT emp_name AS MANAGER 
FROM TABLE  
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM Table)
```

I am getting all the managers with this query, but I also want to see the sum of who are under managers.

For example

```
MANAGER  SUM
-------------
A        3
B        2
C        1
```

How I can do the sum?

Comment: That's not a **SUM** - that's a **COUNT** ....

Comment: Google recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Add `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`, and use a CTE.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
 manager_id
FROM
 table
GROUP BY
 manager_id
)
SELECT 
 t.emp_name AS MANAGER, 
 COUNT(t.emp_id) AS SUM
FROM 
 table as t
  INNER JOIN
 cte as c
  ON
   t.emp_id = c.manager_id
GROUP BY
 t.emp_name
```